# What are rules of comparing pointer to superclass with pointer to subclass?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, multiple-inheritance

Simple definition:

```
class B1 
{ /* stuff, virtual methods */ };

class B2 
{ /* stuff, virtual methods */ };

class D : public B1, public B2
{ /* stuff, overrides*/ };
```

Some variables:

```
D obj;
B1 *bp1 = &obj;
B2 *bp2 = &obj;
```

Question, how do following tests behave in C++?

```
assert(&obj == bp1);
assert(bp1 == &obj);

assert(&obj == bp2);
assert(bp2 == &obj);

assert(bp1 == bp2);
assert(bp2 == bp1);
```

Is there UB? Are any of those well-defined? Are there implicit static casts happening?

---

To state the question differently, looking at [cppreference.com link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) given in comments, what does this mean, when determining the types used in pointer comparison above:

> **Pointer comparison operators**

...

> 4. If the types of the operands are P1, a pointer to (possibly
>    cv-qualified) T1, and P2, a pointer to (possibly cv-qualified) T2, and
>    if T1 is the same as T2 or is a base class of T2, then the composite
>    pointer type is the cv-combined type of P1 and P2. Otherwise, if T2 is
>    a base class of T1, then the composite pointer type is the cv-combined
>    type of P2 and P1.

...

> In the definition above, cv-combined type of two pointer types P1 and
> P2 is a type P3 that has the same number of levels and type at every
> level as P1, except that cv-qualifications at every level are set as
> follows:
>
> a) at every level other than top level, the union of the
> cv-qualifications of P1 and P2 at that level, b) if the resulting
> cv-qualification at any level is different from P1's or P2's
> cv-qualification at the same level, then const is added to every level
> between the top level and this one.

...or is this unrelated snippet and code snippets above are covered elsewhere?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison - in "Pointer comparison operators". It's explained what kind of conversions are behind these comparisons. I don't see any UB in your example, all seems to be well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit `static_cast`s are happening.

Comparing the pointer to derived with a pointer to base will cast the derived pointer to base type, adjusting it in the process.

Comparing different base pointers is not allowed, as these are not convertible.

Comment: Are you sure the order of operands does not matter? The page  at cppreference.com linked in a comment seems to make distinction between order of operands, not always casting to base class.

Comment: Not `static_cast`s, just conversions. I don't think it will ever attempt a conversion that can't be done implicitly.

Comment: @hyde What part of that page makes a distinction? I can't find anything.

Comment: *"if T1 is the same as T2 or is a base class of T2, then the composite pointer type is the cv-combined type of P1 and P2. Otherwise, if T2 is a base class of T1, then the composite pointer type is the cv-combined type of P2 and P1."*. It separately, explicitly lists both orders, "P1 and P2" vs "P2 and P1". It's probably just convoluted way of saying it and both cases are the same, but I can't decipher the text enough to be 100% confident of that.

Comment: @hyde You seem to be assuming that P1 is the left-hand and P2 the right-hand operand, but that's not what it says.

Comment: The `operator==` for pointer types cannot be a member function, so type conversion rules are symmetrical, because none of the arguments is "special".